# Как перевернуть коллекцию моделей в php

Tags: php, laravel

Как перевернуть коллекцию моделей в php фреймворке laravel?

Comment: Что значит - перевернуть коллекцию?

Comment: Есть массив [0, 1, 2]
Переворачиваем его, теперь он [2, 1, 0]
А мне нужно перевернуть коллекцию моделей в laravel

Comment: $myModels = array_reverse($myModels->toArray())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Данные модели полученные методами `all()` и `get()` возвращают экземпляр `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` ([документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#collections)). В документации описаны методы по работе с [коллекциями](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods). Что бы перевернуть коллекцию, можно использовать метод [reverse()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-reverse).

```
$collection = collect(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);

$reversed = $collection->reverse();

$reversed->all();

/*
    [
        4 => 'e',
        3 => 'd',
        2 => 'c',
        1 => 'b',
        0 => 'a',
    ]
*/
```